# Netlogo, creating breed at the center of a particular polygon (i.e with id = 123456)

Tags: netlogo

I have a netlogo gis model. the gis shape file consists of building footprint (in the form of polygons). I want to create a breed at the center of particular building with id = "66445345" (polygon id). There is large no of buildings/ polygons but I am only interested in creating the breed at this one polygon
Any ideas how to do this?

```
breed [blds bld]

set guo-building gis:load-dataset "guo-building.shp"
gis:drawing-color gray
gis:draw guo-buildings 1.0

foreach gis:vertex-list-of guo-buildings[
    i ->
    let bld-no gis:property-value i "id"
    let center gis:centroid-of i
    let center-location gis:location-of center

    if bld-no = 66445345
      [create-blds 1
      [
       set xcor (item 0 center-location)
       set ycor (item 1 center-location)
       set color red
       set size 5
      ]
      ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

sorted the problem. Need insert blds-own variable and store id.

```
breeds [blds bld]
breeds-own [building-no]
to setup-pma-locations
foreach gis:feature-list-of guo-buildings[
i ->
  let bld-no gis:property-value i "ID"
  let center gis:centroid-of i 
  let center-coordinates gis:location-of center

  if not empty? center-coordinates [
    create-blds 1
    [
     set xcor (item 0 center-coordinates)
     set ycor (item 1 center-coordinates)
     set color red
     set size 0
     set building-no bld-no  ;store in blds-own variable
    ]

    ]
    ] 
ask blds[
let pma blds with [building-no = "66445345"]
  ask pma [set color red
  set size 5]
]
```